# Pedra-papel-tesoura-lagarto-Spock no Uri Online Judge ex. 1873, mas ele não aceita

Tags: c

Minha tentativa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char rajesh[15], sheldon[15];
  char pedra[] = "pedra", papel[] = "papel", tesoura[] = "tesoura",
  lagarto[] = "lagarto", spock[] = "spock";
  int c, i, comp;

  printf("Digite a quantidade de casos de teste: \n");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  for(i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    printf("Digite uma frase: \n");
    scanf(" %s %s", rajesh, sheldon);
    comp = strcmp(rajesh, sheldon);
    if(comp == 0) {
      printf("empate\n");
    }
    if(comp != 0) {
      if((strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      }

      if((strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      }

      if((strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, lagarto) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      }

      if((strcmp(rajesh, lagarto) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      }

      if((strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Link do enunciado: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1873

Comment: Coloca o tipo de erro que ele retorna. Se tu for esperar que alguém logue ou crie uma conta só pra testar teu código, descobrir a resposta e então tentar te ajudar, acho que a resposta vai demorar

Comment: Ele retorna esse erro: Wrong answer (40%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhe isso:

```
    if(comp == 0) {
      printf("empate\n");
    }
    if(comp != 0) {
```

Ora, se o primeiro `if` entrar, automaticamente o segundo não entra e vice-versa. Logo, é melhor usar um `else` aqui ao invés de um outro `if`.

Depois, esses montes de `if`s eram para ser `else if`:

```
      if((strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      } else if((strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0))){
        printf("radesh\n");
      } else if((strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0) ||
        (strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0))){
        printf("sheldon\n");
      }
```

O motivo é que ele só deve cair em um `printf`. Do jeito que você fez, sem forçar tudo a ser `else if`, vários `printf`s são disparados.

O código fica assim:

```
    if (comp == 0) {
        printf("empate\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0) || (strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0))) {
        printf("radesh\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0) || (strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0))) {
        printf("sheldon\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0) || (strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0))) {
        printf("radesh\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0) || (strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0))) {
        printf("sheldon\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0) || (strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0))) {
        printf("radesh\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, lagarto) == 0) || (strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0))) {
        printf("sheldon\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(rajesh, lagarto) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0) || (strcmp(sheldon, papel) == 0))) {
        printf("radesh\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(sheldon, lagarto) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0) || (strcmp(rajesh, papel) == 0))) {
        printf("sheldon\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(rajesh, spock) == 0) && ((strcmp(sheldon, tesoura) == 0) || (strcmp(sheldon, pedra) == 0))) {
        printf("radesh\n");
    } else if ((strcmp(sheldon, spock) == 0) && ((strcmp(rajesh, tesoura) == 0) || (strcmp(rajesh, pedra) == 0))) {
        printf("sheldon\n");
    }
```

Depois, observe essas duas linhas:

```
  printf("Digite a quantidade de casos de teste: \n");
    printf("Digite uma frase: \n");
```

Os problemas do URI são extremamente rigorosos e inflexíveis quanto ao formato de entrada e saída, até mesmo um espaço em branco a mais ou a menos faz com que ele diga que o seu programa está errado. Essas duas mensagens acima irão aparecer na saída e fazer o URI considerar a sua solução inválida. Retire essas mensagens.

Aliás, o formato da URI também não tolera qualquer erro de digitação ou ortografia na saída. O nome do jogador é *ra**j**esh* e não *ra**d**esh*.

E temos isso:

```
    scanf(" %s %s", rajesh, sheldon);
```

Tem certeza que não era para ser `"%s %s"` ao invés de `" %s %s"`? Acho que esse espaço em branco no começo pode te atrapalhar.

Há mais um monte de coisas que eu poderia sugerir para que esse monte de `if`s fiquem com uma estrutura legal e não essa coisa horrorosa e repetitiva. No entanto, aí eu teria que praticamente reescrever o seu programa inteiro.

Comment: Perdoem a bagunça no código, ainda estou aprendendo a programar. Eu fiz as alterações no código mas o Uri ainda não aceito. Mesmo assim, queria agradecer as dicas, e obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Problema resolvido pessoal. Mas uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda Victor.

Comment: @AndréMoreira Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 